# How to emphasise the insignificance of someone/thing – besides using "klein"

Tags: expression, french

We were having a conversation in French about asteroids, and I said:

> Je ne suis peut-être pas expert en astronomie, mais... Qu’est-ce qu’un **petit** humain **de rien du tout** peut contre quelque chose d’aussi imposant, si ça reprend la route direction Terre ?

I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in German. This is where I'd have said:

> ≈ In der Astronomie bin ich zwar nicht sonderlich erfahren, aber ... Was könnte ein **kleiner** Mensch je gegen solch ein überwältigend großes Objekt ausrichten, wenn es direkt auf die Erde zusteuerte?

---

The expression "*X de rien du tout*", literally meaning "*X of nothing at all*", is used to emphasise the insignificance / Bedeutungslosigkeit of X, added on to the similarly functioning word "*petit*".

In German, I'd use "*klein*", but the phrasing seems rather lacking in comparison.

Comment: Note you can use "der kleine Mensch" to denote humanity as a concept, rather than an individual.

Comment: @JohnHennig Not quite. In this instance, "peut" alone makes for an idiomatic phrasing, actually.

Answer (score 10):

I would propose the word "unbedeutend", either to replace *klein* or adding it. Also I would add "wie ich"(like myself) after *Mensch* (if you're reffering to yourself):

> Was könnte ein kleiner, unbedeutender Mensch wie ich je gegen [...]
>
> Was könnte ein unbedeutender Mensch wie ich je gegen[...]

Comment: My problem with this solution is that by emphasizing "*ich als unbedeutender Mensch*" you allude that some other, more significant person could actually do something about the situation. Which in the scenario we are talking about seems impossible. So, basically you are sending your audience into a wrong direction. (Broader discussion of this problem in my separate answer.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is this sentence with some stylistic improvements (more idiomatic German; register of speech: casual but not sloppy oral communicaiton):

> Ich habe zwar nicht viel Ahnung von Astronomie, aber: Was könnte die Menschheit je gegen so ein riesiges Objekt ausrichten, wenn es direkt auf die Erde zuraste?

This does perhaps not answer your question for better terms for "kleiner Mensch" (e.g. winziger Mensch). But I do not find the entire sentence very idiomatic. One thing is the picture that the sentence evokes: it presents us one single person trying to stop the asteroid. However, more realistically, this would be a project for not one single person but rather for (hopefully) the entire planet, or at least 2-3 of the larger countries who have the most advanced equipment. So I think it would be most natural to speak of *die Menschheit*. Now, the *Menschheit* ist a pretty large thing, or at least a numerous one. Speaking of a "tiny" *Menschheit* would be strange. If you anyway want to stress the insignificance of the *Menschheit* as compared to the power of the asteroid, you could perhaps say:

> Ich bin zwar kein Experte für Astronomie, aber: Was könnte die Menschheit in ihrer ganzen Winzigkeit [or: Schwäche] je gegen so ein riesiges Objekt ausrichten, wenn es direkt auf die Erde zuraste?

Other stylistical notes:

- "zusteuerte" is not a good choice here for what the asteroid does. The asteroid does not have the ability to redirect its trajectory, so there is no "steuern" there. Therefore I use *rasen*.
- "überwältigend groß": somehow it does not feel right. One would not say *überwältigend groß* for an asteroid. I do not have a fool-proof explanation for this, but I think we use *überwältigend* rather for emotional effects, not for physical dimensions. So a good concert could be *überwältigend*, or the love of a woman, or whatever. For physically large things you simply can use *riesig*.

As this answer was  more about the entire sentence, not specifically about "un petit humain de rien du tout": If you want solutions for this in German, please give some more expamples in French (from other areas than astronomy perhaps).

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to switch to a metaphor as

> Was könnte ich als *Erdenwurm* gegen so ein riesiges Objekt ausrichten...

Here *Wurm* is representative for a small and weak animal.

Comment: Or just "ein  [kleiner] Wurm"

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can always use the diminutive. It fits so-so in this special case and may feel a little old-fashioned (["Das tapfere Schneiderlein"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_tapfere_Schneiderlein)).

> Was könnte so ein [kleines/unbedeutendes/unmaßgebliches] **Menschlein** schon gegen einen Asteroiden ausrichten?

One could also simply use a more elaborate expression, as in your French original:

> Was kann ein Mensch, **an dem so gar nichts Besonderes ist,** gegen einen Asteroiden schon ausrichten?

Even better is a specific noun like *Wicht* or guidot's *Wurm*, and a specific adjective to signify insignificance:

> Was können wir **armseligen Wichte,** denen es an allem fehlt, gegen einen Asteroiden schon ausrichten?

If the insignificance is social rather than physical one could consider adjectives like ***nichtswürdig*.**

Answer (score 2):

There are already enough suggestions, but I think that that they sound either unnatural or take too much freedom with respect to the original. Thus, yet another translation.

I would say:

> Ich bin vielleicht kein Experte in Astronomie, aber: Was kann denn ein einfacher, unbedeutender Mensch gegen ein solch gewaltiges Objekt ausrichten, falls es einen Kollisionskurs Richtung Erde aufnimmt.
>
> *Original*: 
> Je ne suis peut-être pas expert en astronomie, mais... Qu’est-ce qu’un petit humain de rien du tout peut contre quelque chose d’aussi imposant, si ça reprend la route direction Terre ?

My choices:

- *petit humain* --> *unbedeutender Mensch*
- *de rien du tout* --> *einfacher*
- *quelque chose d'aussi imposant* --> *ein solch gewaltiges Objekt*
- *peut contre*: *ausrichten gegen*
- *la route direction terre* --> *einen Kollisionskurs Richtung Erde*

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to emphasize the insignificance of a human (or humankind, as [Christian Geiselmann elaborates on in his answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54033/20503)), why not just use that term?

> In der Astronomie bin ich zwar nicht sonderlich erfahren, aber ... Was könnte ein kleiner, im Vergleich geradezu insignifikanter Mensch je gegen solch ein überwältigend großes Objekt ausrichten, wenn es direkt auf die Erde zusteuerte?

"Insignifikant" may feel a little anglicised since the term exists in English as well, but [it is indeed a german word](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/insignifikant) (derived from Latin, not English).

An alternative would be using "bedeutungslos" in place of "insignifikant"; the Duden (linked above) also uses this to explain the meaning of "insignifikant". Note that [miep mentions this in his answer as well](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54032/20503); I don't mean to rip his answer off, but it just so happens that the Duden uses this term to explain "insignifikant".

> In der Astronomie bin ich zwar nicht sonderlich erfahren, aber ... Was könnte ein kleiner, im Vergleich völlig bedeutungsloser Mensch je gegen solch ein überwältigend großes Objekt ausrichten, wenn es direkt auf die Erde zusteuerte?

Of course, this can also be adapted for a sentence talking about humankind; I'll reuse [Christian Geiselmann's adaptation of your sentence](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54033/20503) for this:

> Ich bin zwar kein Experte für Astronomie, aber: Was könnte die Menschheit in ihrer ganzen Insignifikanz/Bedeutungslosigkeit je gegen so ein riesiges Objekt ausrichten, wenn es direkt auf die Erde zuraste?

Comment: I agree with your approach: as you put it, you do not refer to a single person, rather to *der Mensch* as a term for *mankind*, which seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another try:

> Auch wenn ich mich (jetzt) mit Astronomie nicht auskenne, nur: Was hätte denn so ein Nichts an physischer Masse wie ein Menschenwesen etwas so Gewaltigem entgegenzusetzen, das sich (wieder?) Richtung Erde bewegt?

- I wanted to reflect the idea of '*rien (du tout)*'.
- There is no '**moi**' (narrateur / interlocuteur) in the second sentence.
- Why did the author write '*reprend*' and not '*prend*'?

Since I don't know the context, I don't know the kind of '*rien du tout*' the author is thinking about, and 'Masse' just may be one.